# text file returning null and 0.0

Tags: java, arrays, null

I am trying to read a text file with 6 elements in it and put it into two arrays. The first element of the text I'm trying to read is a string and the second is a double. However when I call `println` to verify the output, it prints `null` and `0.0`.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class inputFile {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

    String [] studNum = new String [25];
    double [] grade = new double [25];



    File findFile = new File ("//Users//luiserojas//Documents//holaFile.txt");
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner (findFile);

    int index = 0;

        while (inFile.hasNext()){
            studNum [index] = inFile.next();
            grade [index] = inFile.nextDouble();
            index ++;
            System.out.println(studNum[index] + grade[index]); 
        }

        }

}
```

Comment: There is the problem with the index as the answers indicate but in order to read Strings from a file you need inFile.hasNextLine() and the you have to split the String. In the way you write it, it reads only a token in every loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're incrementing `index` before you print items so you try to print items that were not yet added, which have default-constructed values of `null` and `0.0d` your arrays are filled with when they're created. Just reordering the following lines like this shall help:

```
        System.out.println(studNum[index] + grade[index]); 
        index ++;
```

Comment: thanks you so much for your input... I knew it was something really noob on my part! it makes total sense and it works now...

Answer (score 1):

You are incrementing `index` before you print the values, nothing is stored there yet. You need to put `index++` after the `println()`

Comment: thank you so much for your input... I knew it was something really noob on my part! it makes total sense...

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the values after the incrementing of index,So default values are dsiplaying.So first print and next increment index like this.

```
while (inFile.hasNext()){
            studNum [index] = inFile.next();
            grade [index] = inFile.nextDouble();
            System.out.println(studNum[index] + grade[index]); 
            index ++;
        }
```